# Check configuration of mongodb setup

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-shell

I have setup mongodb for cluster environment. My config server and router is running on one machine, whereas sharding is running on three different machine. I want to know if any command available which I can run on terminal(On which configsvr and router is running) and it will display all routername,configserver(associated with it),Other sharded databases(associated with it).

To simplify it more.

Suppose I run mycommand/piece of code, it display.

```
router1---> configserver1----> Shardeddb1
                         ----> Shardeddb2
                         -----> shardeddb3
```

Modifying to make it more clear.

My router1 and configserver1 are running on single machine(say ip 19.0.0.123),   Shardeddb1(say ip 19.0.0.124),Shardeddb2(say ip 19.0.0.125),Shardeddb3(say ip 19.0.0.126).

I want to make Shardeddb1 as a primary and (Shardeddb2,Shardeddb3) as secondary. If I run sh.status(); it show me details but not about which database belong to which machine. So is there any script which can show me more details?

```
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("545b632e9be3f019d6ef788f")
}
shards:
    {  "_id" : "ps1",  "host" : "ps1/19.0.0.123:27017","draining" : true }
    {  "_id" : "ps2",  "host" : "ps2/19.0.0.124:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "19.0.0.125:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "19.0.0.126:27017" }
databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "demo",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "db",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "ps1" }
    {  "_id" : "mongotestDB",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "ps1" }
            mongotestDB.logcoll
                    shard key: { "id" : 1 }
                    chunks:
                            shard0000       4
                            shard0001       9
                            ps2     7
                            ps1     5
                    too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

Comment: Markus makes some good points below. I think you may want a better understanding of sharding architecture and then you can reevaluate your question. Naively, [`sh.status`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.status/#sh.status) is the closest to what you're looking for in terms of a mongo shell function.

Comment: The primary shard (not to confuse with the primary member of a replica set) for each database should be shown by the output of `sh.status()`. Can you please post yours?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have added sh.status()

Comment: Your setup differs a bit from what you have shown. But have a look at the databases section: the primary shard for each database is given.

Comment: Actually I want to remove shard ps1 but not able to do so.Its showing me on "draining" state but not removing it. Why I am not able to see secondary shard?

Answer (score 0):

Since your diagram shows otherwise:

1. You can either have exactly 1 or 3 config servers.
2. You should ***always*** have your `mongos` instances have the *exact* same string for the configdb parameter. And this string has to hold all config servers in the same order. **Otherwise, you risk metadata corruption.**
3. All configservers and mongos need to be able to connect to and be connected by all nodes in the cluster.
4. The easiest way to have an overview on your cluster is the free [MongoDB Management Service](https://mms.mongodb.com) monitoring.
5. Running `mongos'` and configservers on the same machine is possible - as long as you keep an eye on the load. If things get rough, and the configservers have delays in updating the metadata because the `mongos` consume all the IO, you might worsen things. If chunk splits are delayed (and they are more likely under high load), this might cause JumboChunks, which have to be split manually and - until this is done - can't be migrated. Therefor, it is a Very Bad Idea™ to have mongos instances run on the configservers, imvho. A far better solution is to have the mongos instances run on the application servers, one on each.

Comment: For #5, what kind of IO are you talking about? Disk? mongos has no data directories and doesn't store much, if anything on disk, so I don't think it should fight with the config servers over disk I/O. Generally, mongos belong on an application server since mongos are lightweight enough to coexist and it saves network hops.

Comment: Network IO. I have seen people running both a mongos and a configserver on small VPS and it started to become a problem. Actually, we noticed it only after another mongos tried to update it's metadata cache. And I totally agree with you: mongos on an _appserver_ is the best thing one can do.

Comment: @wdberkeley: Rethinking this, I am not too sure wether RAM couldn't be/wasn't a problem, too. Albeit the metadata is tiny, I honestly don't know too much of mongos RAM consumption under extreme load. Could that become a problem on small - tiny instances, too?

Comment: I don't think so. I can't imagine the cluster metadata getting so large that the part that is cached on mongos would be a significant chunk of memory. You could force mongos to hold a lot of documents in memory if you had a large batch size on a cursor, I suppose.

Comment: @wdberkeley: Well, or _a lot_ of cursors, probably. Thanks a lot for the info, nevertheless.